# Flaw in `adb shell ime list -a`?

Tags: adb, shell, input-methods

I wanted to understand how to work with IMEs. More precisely, I was trying to figure out how to disable in a single command one can disable all the input methods so that the hardware keyboard takes over. I thought that the detailed description given about each input method on giving the

```
adb shell ime list -a
```

command (with an emulator instance running on my 12.04 64-bit Ubuntu machine) might help me.

Here I accidentally observed (see the pic below) that in spite of the disabling the various IMEs and then giving the IME listing command, `enabled=true` stays!

[image: IME list command bug?]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enabled=true` in this list tells whether the IME's *service* is enabled in its manifest; that is, whether the developer of the IME has allowed it to appear in that list. It has nothing to do with whether it's turned on or off in the settings.