# How to disable softkeyboard in cyanogenmod 10.0.0 parmanently?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard, linux

I want to disable the soft keyboard on asus tf300t permanently. I have read a lot of post on stackoverflow that allow you to block the soft keyboard but all of them explain how to do them in a specific app. I have root access to the device. its running cyanogenmod 10.0.0 on it. it has a dock keyboard. I could not find the .apk fie in /system/app for the soft keyboard that I could remove. does someone know how to remove the soft keyboard ?

thank you

Comment: I remember having read about a method to disable a given IME (Input Method) via ADB, but cannot find it currently (see also: [Flaw in `adb shell ime list -a`?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47557/16575) for a starter). But this hint might give you an idea what to look out for, I hope...

Comment: I found a file /system/app/LatinIME.apk

This file is responsible for the soft keyboard. I tried to change the name of the file from the terminal but it wont allow me to do so. kept giving an error "Read only file"

So I installed root explorer. in root explorer there is a tab top right that enables you to mount R/W to rename that file.

then I went back to the terminal and renamed the file so the system does not recognize the file. this blocks the soft keyboard from poping up on anywhere in the cyanogenmod.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the clean way to do it. It had been cleaner to *disable* the app (than to remove/rename it), which could be done with e.g. `pm` (the Android package manager) via `adb shell`. But whatever you like, as long as it solves your issue :)